# Convert rsync exclude patterns to explicit list of files

Tags: rsync, wildcards

I am trying to find out if there is ways to convert a long list of `rsync` exclude patterns, that I am maintaining for the purpose of making sensible backups, to an explicit list of file and directory names.

The application is that I am trying to use the same list (whenever I update it by adding or removing a pattern) for a different application (`mksquashfs`). Both tools allow explicit file lists with one entry per line to be specified as exlude list, but the syntax for the patterns differs in details.

You may assume that the list to be converted consists of all kinds patterns, possibly including wildcards, allowed by `rsync`.

Two approaches are conceivable:

1. Find out what `rsync` uses under the hook (it seems to be neither simple shell globbing nor `find`)
2. Use `rsync` to produce the list by doing a `--dry-run` dummy transfer with verbose output (here I am not sure how to have it print the names of the excluded files)

Comment: Depending on the glob, there could be a very large number of files the exclude (many of which don’t exist yet)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Sure. I would run the conversion just before I run the concerned backup scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: 
where `"${other_opts[@]}"` indocates your normal rsync arguments.

```
rsync --dry-run --debug=FILTER  "${other_opts[@]}" /proc/$$/no-such-dir/
```

Should print out all the excluded files.

```
[sender] hiding file .bash_history-27611.tmp because of pattern *.tmp
[sender] hiding file .bash_history-21217.tmp because of pattern *.tmp
[sender] hiding file .bash_history-29735.tmp because of pattern *.tmp
[sender] hiding file .bash_history-20437.tmp because of pattern *.tmp
```

you can chop that up using sed.

```
sed '/^\[sender\] hiding file .* because of / {
  s/^\[sender\] hiding file \(.*\) because of .*/\1/
  p
  }
d '
```

but this might break if you encounter filenames that contain control characters.